# ctex package installation error

Tags: fontspec, expl3, ctex

I just installed `ctex` today, and used `\usepackage{ctex}`, only to get these errors:

`` Package ctex Error: Support package `fontspec' too old. ... { ctex } { package-too-old } { fontspec } } ``

`` Package ctex Error: Support package `expl3' too old. ...rror:nnn { ctex } { l3-too-old } { expl3 } } ``
`` Package zhnumber Error: File `{UTF8}' not found. \ProcessKeysOptions { zhnum / options } ``

How do I fix this? I am using LuaLaTeX with TeXstudio.

Comment: You need to update your packages `fontspec` and `l3kernel` to run the most current `ctex`.

Comment: I used MikTeX update via admin and it worked (although the user and admin package settings/updates or something are out of sync). The output came out fine, though.